# Streaming image artefacts

Tags: android, mobile, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

when I watched videos on my mobile phone I never noticed any image artefacts. Most of the time I was connected to a Wi-Fi and the streaming protocol was HLS. On error the video just stopped, crashed or showed me a load indicator.

That’s why I would ask on which faults you can see image artefacts? If the streaming protocol or the device detect image artefacts in error cases? And which image artefacts you guys has seen.

Thanks!

Comment: @AndiGeeky   
It’s more about what I want to try is relevant.   
I never streamed a video connected through a cell network. And with a WiFi connection I only noticed the three states: stopped, crashed or load indicator. And never any image artefacts (with my own written Player or with another one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image artefacts are caused by errors in the video stream. The errors are a result of bad input stream, errors made by the encoder, errors during transfer and so on. Some errors are fatal, from others the decoder can recover - this depends on the decoder itself. IMHO android video capabilities are very poor.